# Paged Media @page:nth selector

Tags: css, printing, css-selectors, css-paged-media

According to http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/ there is the @page:first selector. But what if I want to define different footers or headers for specific pages?

Answer (score -2):

You can use multiple headers, each of which will then become the  for that section of the document.
Read more [here](http://html5doctor.com/the-header-element/).

Comment: Link is about putting `header` tags in markup - not what OP is asking for.